# inserting content into div with javascript

Tags: javascript

dI am succesfully placing text in a div using javascript. However I also want to add images to the text but my javascript method does not seem to accept this. I am using the following code for the text:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "This a bit of text";
```

See the [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhj9Lhs4/)

Just adding an img tag within the text hasn't worked. Anyone?

Eddy.

And what if I wanted to add the possibility to enlarged the photo using the following script.

```
<div class="slider jcarousel fancybox" data-jcarousel="true" style="position: relative; width: auto; margin-top: -1px; z-index: 99;">
<ul style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
<li class="product slide" style="width: auto; border: none;"><a class="zoom first" rel="" href="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" title=“Test image”><img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" alt=“Test image“ /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How would I place this within the text?

Comment: Where is the code you tried and didn't work?

Comment: "Just adding an img tag within the text hasn't worked" - I don't see your attempt. And adding an img tag **will** work.

Answer (score 0):

To add images in HTML text you must escape quotes using `\` before or use `'` instead of `"` in attributes or string.

If you don't that, then you'll see an error in the browser's console.
This is wrong:
`document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<img src="img.png">"//img.png is outside of the string`

Examples:

`document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<img src=\"img.png\"/>"`
`document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='<img src="img.png">'`
`document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<img src='img.png'/>"`

How did you try to add the image?

Comment: with document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<img src=\"img.png\"/>"

Comment: @Eddy Are you sure that the image exists (which you tried to add before)? THIS SHOULD REALLY works. It's working here. `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png\"/>This a bit of text";`

Comment: @Eddy I think there are no errors... because you said that you get to change the div text in, but you didn't get it to add images because probably the URL may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert images with innerHtml. Just use `''` marks instead of `""`.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = 'This a bit of text <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" />';
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3ynz9bL/)**

Comment: Thanks!!  What now if I wanted to add a enlarged for the photo using the following script as added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = " <img src=' // image path ...'/>This a bit of text";
```

this way you can add image easily. but please make sure that you are addind image with proper path
OR if it will not work then,
add `<img />` tag in HTML. like:

`<div id="myDiv">
<img src="..image path..." />
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `innerHTML`. This is a better way of doing it:

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.textContent = "This a bit of text";

var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = "http://placehold.it/100x50";

myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan.How would I get my "slider jcarousel fancy box" in there. See the code in my initial question above please.

Comment: You could hire a developer. Or maybe read the documentation if you want to do it yourself.